# Superimposing a log-normal density in ggplot and stat_function()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to superimpose a function via `stat_function()` in `ggplot` but can't figure out my mistake. this example produces a nice looking plot:

```
data <- data.frame(x=rt(10000, df=7))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  stat_function(fun =dnorm, size=1, color='gray', args=list()) +
  opts(title="Histogram of interest rate changes") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

but when i try to superimpose a log-normal density this doesn't work as expected (or should I say as expected this doesn't work ;):

```
data <- data.frame(x=rf(10000, df1=7, df2=120))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
 stat_function(fun =dnorm, size=1, color='gray', args=list(log=TRUE)) +
 opts(title="Histogram of interest rate changes") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

so here's my hopefully simple question: what am I doing wrong here? I guess this is a really simple problem I just don't see the answer - sorry.

Comment: I don't get how a desnsity can be negative.

Comment: I think part of your problem is `log=TRUE`

Comment: @LucianoSelzer of course you were right - and I thought it would work via the `log=TRUE` argument but as Sven demonstrated there is an easier way ;)

Comment: `log = TRUE` computes the probabilities in logaritm it doesn't change the distribution. I let's you have improved precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dlnorm`, the density function of the log-normal distribution:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  stat_function(fun = dlnorm, size=1, color='gray') +
  opts(title="Histogram of interest rate changes") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Just ran across your answer. I would appreciate, if you could take a look at my related question (in case you haven't seen it): http://stackoverflow.com/q/25598485/2872891. Thank you!