# R: add normal fits to grouped histograms in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, normal-distribution

I am on the lookout for the most elegant way to superimpose normal distribution fits in grouped histograms in `ggplot2`. I know this question has been asked many times before, but none of the proposed options, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182556/how-to-add-gaussian-curve-to-histogram-created-with-qplot) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376967/using-stat-function-and-facet-wrap-together-in-ggplot2-in-r) struck me as very elegant, at least not unless `stat_function` could be made to work on each particular subsection of the data.

One relatively elegant way to superimpose a normal distribution fit onto a non-grouped histogram that I did come across was using `geom_smooth` and `method="nls"` (aside from the fact then that it's not a self-starting function and that starting values have to be specified) :

```
library(ggplot2)
myhist = data.frame(size = 10:27, counts = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 13L, 23L, 31L, 40L, 42L, 22L, 14L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L) )
ggplot(data=myhist, aes(x=size, y=counts)) + geom_point() + 
     geom_smooth(method="nls", formula = y ~ N * dnorm(x, m, s), se=F, 
                 start=list(m=20, s=5, N=300))
```

[image]

I was wondering though whether this approach could also be used to add normal distribution fits to grouped histograms as in

```
library(devtools)
install_github("tomwenseleers/easyGgplot2",type="source")
library("easyGgplot2") # load weight data
ggplot(weight,aes(x = weight)) + 
+     geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count.., colour=sex, fill=sex),alpha=0.5,position="identity")
```

[image]

I was also wondering if there are any packages that might define a `+ stat_distrfit()` or `+ stat_normfit(`) for `ggplot2` by any chance (with the possibility for grouping) ? (I couldn't really find anything, but this would seem like a common enough task, so I was just wondering)

Reason I want the code to be as short as possible is that this is for a course, and that I want to keep things as easy as possible...

PS `geom_density` does not suit my goal and I would also like to plot the counts/frequencies as opposed to the density. I would also like to have them in the same panel, and avoid using `facet_wrap`

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25075428#25091231).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
## simulate your dataset - could not get easyGplot2 to load....
set.seed(1)     # for reproducible example
weight <- data.frame(sex=c("Female","Male"), weight=rnorm(1000,mean=c(65,67),sd=1))

library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)       # for fitdistr(...)
get.params <- function(z) with(fitdistr(z,"normal"),estimate[1:2])
df <- aggregate(weight~sex, weight, get.params)
df <- data.frame(sex=df[,1],df[,2])
x  <- with(weight, seq(min(weight),max(weight),len=100))
gg <- data.frame(weight=rep(x,nrow(df)),df)
gg$y <- with(gg,dnorm(x,mean,sd))
gg$y <- gg$y * aggregate(weight~sex, weight,length)$weight * diff(range(weight$weight))/30

ggplot(weight,aes(x = weight, colour=sex)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count.., fill=sex), alpha=0.5,position="identity") +
  geom_line(data=gg, aes(y=y))
```

I suppose "elegant" is in the eye of the beholder. The problem with using `stat_function(...)` is that the `args=...` list cannot be mapped using `aes(...)`, as the post in the comments explains. So you have to create an auxiliary data.frame (`gg` in this example) that has the x- and y-values for the fitted distributions, and use `geom_line(...)`.

The code above uses `fitdistr(...)` in the `MASS` package to calculate maximum likelihood estimates of the mean and sd of your data, grouped by gender, based on the normality assumption (you can use a different distribution if that makes sense). It then creates an x-axis by dividing the range in `weight` into 100 increments, and calculates `dnorm(x,...)` for the appropriate mean and sd. Since the result is density, we have to adjust that using:

```
gg$y <- gg$y * aggregate(weight~sex, weight,length)$weight * diff(range(weight$weight))/30
```

because you want to map this against count data. Note that this assumes you use the default binning in geom_histogram (which divides the range in x into 30 equal increments). Finally, we add the call to `geom_line(...)` using `gg` as the layer-specific dataset.

Comment: Many thanks for this - yes this was what I was looking for! Still a bit surprising that stat_function() cannot be mapped - I really don't see any intrinsic reason why that shouldn't be possible to implement sooner or later... I'll try to wrap this in a ggplot2.normhist() function in my easyGgplot2 fork to save my students a bit of code... :-)