# fit a normal distribution to grouped data, giving expected frequencies

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, normal-distribution

I have a frequency distribution of observations, grouped into counts within class intervals.
I want to fit a normal (or other continuous) distribution, and find the expected frequencies in each interval according to that distribution.

For example, suppose the following, where I want to calculate another column, `expected` giving the
expected number of soldiers with chest circumferences in the interval given by `chest`, where these
are assumed to be centered on the nominal value. E.g., `35` = `34.5 <= y < 35.5`.  One analysis I've seen gives the expected frequency in this cell as 72.5 vs. the observed 81.

```
> data(ChestSizes, package="HistData")
> 
> ChestSizes
   chest count
1     33     3
2     34    18
3     35    81
4     36   185
5     37   420
6     38   749
7     39  1073
8     40  1079
9     41   934
10    42   658
11    43   370
12    44    92
13    45    50
14    46    21
15    47     4
16    48     1
> 

> # ungroup to a vector of values
> chests <- vcdExtra::expand.dft(ChestSizes, freq="count")
```

There are quite a number of variations of this question, most of which relate to plotting the normal density on top of a histogram, scaled to represent counts not density.  But none explicitly show the calculation of the expected frequencies. One close question is [R: add normal fits to grouped histograms in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423372/r-add-normal-fits-to-grouped-histograms-in-ggplot2)

I can perfectly well do the standard plot (below), but for other things, like a Chi-square test or a `vcd::rootogram` plot, I need the expected frequencies in the same class intervals.

```
> bw <- 1
n_obs <- nrow(chests)
xbar <- mean(chests$chest)
std <- sd(chests$chest)

plt <-
ggplot(chests, aes(chest))  + 
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="lightblue",  binwidth = bw) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 
    dnorm(x, mean = xbar, sd = std) * bw * n_obs,
    color = "darkred", size = 1)

plt
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how you could calculate the expected frequencies for each group assuming Normality.

```
xbar <- with(ChestSizes, weighted.mean(chest, count))
sdx <- with(ChestSizes, sd(rep(chest, count)))
transform(ChestSizes, Expected = diff(pnorm(c(32, chest) + .5, xbar, sdx)) * sum(count))

   chest count     Expected
1     33     3    4.7600583
2     34    18   20.8822328
3     35    81   72.5129162
4     36   185  199.3338028
5     37   420  433.8292832
6     38   749  747.5926687
7     39  1073 1020.1058521
8     40  1079 1102.2356155
9     41   934  943.0970605
10    42   658  638.9745241
11    43   370  342.7971793
12    44    92  145.6089948
13    45    50   48.9662992
14    46    21   13.0351612
15    47     4    2.7465640
16    48     1    0.4579888
```